# accessing database from inside .js file

Tags: javascript, django

I am working on 2 seperate .js files 1)jquery.skitter.js 2)gauge.js
I have a speedometer type gauge which displays a rating.

I need to fetch the rating from a database and put it in the gauge and change it dynamically

```
data-onready="setInterval( function() { Gauge.Collection.get('gauge1').setValue({Insert django function here});}, 4000);"
```

I am using django as back-end and this code is placed inside the skitter.js file's functions.

The problem I am facing is that everytime the skitter is initialised it places images in random order. I have to get the name of the image( which i get using this.settings.label_atual) but how to i go about the next step i.e sending the value of label_atual to the sql query to fetch the ratings ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to execute python code in a javascript file.  Sounds like what you want is AJAX.  There are a number of ways to create an AJAX request, jQuery being a very popular solution.  Here are the docs for `jQuery.post`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/  --- Basically, you need a django page that will receive the data and perform a SQL operation; then you need to use jQuery in your javascript to send the data to your django page.

Comment: $.post( {Django page/function call}, function( data ) {
Gauge.Collection.get('gauge1').setValue({result here});});

Do you mean something like this ?